# What was the motivation behing Poincaré saying that Topology was a disease?

Tags: math-history, motivation

Poincaré once said that:

> "Point set topology is a disease from which the human race will soon recover."

Today we know that he was clearly wrong. What was on his mind when he said that?

Comment: Topology sure has a way of bringing forth some fiery opinion: "In these days the angel of topology and the devil of abstract algebra fight for the soul of every individual discipline of mathematics." - Weyl

Comment: Perhaps he felt like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26613/papers-that-debunk-common-myths-in-the-history-of-mathematics

Answer (score 8):

The purported Poincaré's quotation is about set theory [*Mengenlehere*].

We can see :

- Jeremy Gray, [Did Poincaré say “set theory is a disease” ?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03024067) (1991).

According to Gray, the source is [James Pierpont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Pierpont_(mathematician))'s quotation from a footnote into [Otto Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_H%C3%B6lder)'s *Die mathematische Methode*, 1924, page 556.

Gray translate it as :

> Poincaré at the International Mathematical Congress of 1908 in Rome said that one would later look back on set theory [*Mengenlehere*] as a disease one has overcome.

---

Regarding Poincaré point of view *against* Cantorism, see :

- Henri Poincaré, [Science and method](https://books.google.it/books?id=QPXa2UgysLQC&pg=PA3) (original ed, 1908) :
- Ch.I : **II. The Future of Mathematics**
- Ch.II : **III. Mathematics and Logic**.

Comment: http://documentslide.com/download/link/did-poincare-say-set-theory-is-a-disease